# Snort rule for outgoing attacks

Tags: snort, packet

I have a pcap file captured from a user PC. I need to analyze whether it has initialized a DOS attack to any server.

```
alert tcp any any -> any 8080 (msg:"DOS flood denial of service attempt"; flow:to_server; detection_filter:track by_dst, count 1000, seconds 60; sid:25101; rev:1;)
```

This will give any incoming attacks. How do you write a SNORT rule to detect outbound attacks?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to read a little about basic Snort rules. Have you done research?

Comment: Well I have read the manual up to some extent. I only found that there is no <- direction operator. Still reading the manual. 
http://manual.snort.org/node29.html#SECTION00425000000000000000

Comment: so, what does `any any -> any any` mean according to the manual?

Comment: ip port (Source) -> ip port (Destination)

Comment: exactly. think about that answer for a minute ....

Comment: So you are telling me if I put (user ip) any -> (server ip) (server port) will work ?

Comment: @JKAUSHALYA You might need to read more into the documentation, and a bit further into the filter definition. Particularly, the bit about `flow:to_server`. I'm not all that familiar with Snort, but it looks like that could be important for this case.